# Row-Data-Property of ag-grid table is removed when leaving editing empty cell without change

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-vue

I am using ag grid with vuetify.
If I click into an **empty** cell to edit it and then leave it again **without changing anything**,
the respective property of rowData is completely removed.
I know, to add the property back, you could call handler methods as soon as the table has been touched in any way. But I think this is not optimal. Is there any way to prevent this behavior ?

The dependencies:

```
"ag-grid-community": "26.0.0",
"ag-grid-enterprise": "26.0.0",
"ag-grid-vue": "26.0.0",
```

vue:

```
<ag-grid-vue
          class="ag-theme-balham"
          style="width: 400px; height: 120px"
          :gridOptions="gridOptions"
          :row-data="rowData"
        ></ag-grid-vue>

data() {
    return {
      gridOptions: {
        defaultColDef: {
          editable: true,
        },
        columnDefs: [
          {
            headerName: this.$t('common.c1'),
            field: 'c1',
            width: 100,
            cellStyle: {backgroundColor: 'default'}
          },
          {
            headerName: this.$t(
              'common.c2'
            ),
            field: 'c2',
            width: 100,
            cellStyle: {backgroundColor: 'default'}
          },
          {
            headerName: this.$t(
              'common.c3'
            ),

            field: 'c3',
            width: 198,
          },
        ],
        columnTypes:{
          number: {
            valueFormatter: params => formatNumber(params.value),
            cellClass: 'text-right text-no-wrap',
          },
        },
      },
    }
  },
```

rowData:

```
rowData: [
              { "c1":null,"c2":null,"c3":null },
              { "c1":null,"c2":null,"c3":null },
              { "c1":null,"c2":null,"c3":null },
            ],
```

I changed the dependency versions without any success.

Comment: Give us a working example please